# Sprite Kit Joints

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to make an animated character that can reach out for things on the screen, without moving his torso.

If he can not reach than his hand should go the maximal amount in this direction and then be counteracted by the physical limitation of his static torso.

[image: problem]

So in my code the green rectangle (**hand**) moves where I click and the torso follows. 
I would like to be able to make the red rect (**body**) stationary and make the green rectangle "point" at the touch point position.

I have tried to apply a fixed joint to between the scene and the red body rectangle, but this did not seem to work.

```
- (void) createSceneContent
{
    SKSpriteNode *body = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    body.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:body];

    body.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:body.size];
    body.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    body.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

    self.hand = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(150, 20)];
    self.hand.position = CGPointMake(body.position.x + body.size.width / 2 + self.hand.size.width / 2, body.position.y);
    [self addChild:self.hand];
    self.hand.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.hand.size];
    self.hand.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    self.scene.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:[SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:body.physicsBody bodyB:self.hand.physicsBody anchor:CGPointMake(body.position.x + body.size.width / 2, body.position.y)]];

    [self.hand runAction:[SKAction moveByX:100 y:10 duration:0.1]];
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    [self.hand runAction:[SKAction moveTo:location duration:0.1]];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't really need to use physics here, if you only want the arm to point at the touched location. 
Just change the arm node's `anchorPoint` to the shoulder (where you would put the pin on the joint) and rotate it around that point (the point is held in a helper shoulderNode, so that it's easy to convert to its coordinates later). You can calculate the rotation angle using `atan2f`. Here's the code:

```
- (void) createSceneContent
{
    SKSpriteNode *body = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    body.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:body];

    self.hand = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(150, 20)];
    self.hand.position = CGPointMake(body.position.x + body.size.width*0.5, body.position.y);
    self.hand.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
    [self addChild:self.hand];

    SKNode *shoulderNode = [SKNode node];
    shoulderNode.position = self.hand.position;
    shoulderNode.name = @"shoulderNode";
    [self addChild:shoulderNode];

}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPoint locationConv = [self convertPoint:location toNode:[self childNodeWithName:@"shoulderNode"]];

    self.hand.zRotation = (atan2f(locationConv.y, locationConv.x));
}
```

On the other hand, if you ever need to use physics bodies here, it's probably a bad idea to use SKActions to move the arm, and you also might want to set `body.physicsBody.dynamic = NO` to make the torso static. Then, make sure you add the pin joint correctly, and set its frictionTorque property to a high value to get less dangling. One of the ways to make the hand point at the right location is its velocity vector set in the update method - just use the converted location coordinates (here they are relative to the body node's centre). Full example code:

```
- (void) createSceneContent {
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

    body = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    body.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:body];

    body.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:body.size];
    body.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    body.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;

    self.hand = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 150)];
    // experiment with the anchorPoint for different results
    self.hand.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    self.hand.position = CGPointMake(body.position.x, body.position.y);
    [self addChild:self.hand];

    self.hand.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.hand.size];
    self.hand.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    self.hand.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;

    SKPhysicsJointPin *pinHand = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:body.physicsBody bodyB:self.hand.physicsBody anchor:CGPointMake(body.position.x, body.position.y-5)];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:pinHand];
    // experiment with the friction torque value to achieve desired results
    pinHand.frictionTorque = 1.0;
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    location = [touch locationInNode:self];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    CGPoint locationConv = [self convertPoint:location toNode:body];
    // experiment with the multiplier (here: 10) for faster/slower movement
    self.hand.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(locationConv.x*10, locationConv.y*10);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well this definitely works. Eventually I want to build a more complex character with a two or even more part arm; so coordinating all the rotations would be a little bit of a hassle. I would also like to make this character self contained, so maybe add the hands as children of the body? I am a little bit confused in any case of how to build a scalable character like this easily. Why would you not use physics bodies with SKActions ?

Comment: Having the hands as the body's children will definitely be useful if you want to control the character as an entity. Just remember to realign the positions and the conversion between coordinates appropriately. However, if you want actual complex joints, I recommend you dabble with physics instead (make sure the body is not dynamic, just the arms, and ensure they are not affected by gravity). SKActions used on physicsBodies can lead to erratic behaviour and stuttering, as the rules of the physics world may be in conflict with what the actions might try to do.

Comment: How would you use atan2f in order to calculate the CGVector? I would make a small invisible SpriteNode on the end of the hand that I would connect with a joint. Then I would get the position of a touch in the screen, then apply an impulse to this invisible sprite that is a CGVector with the x component of the point and the y component of the point with a multiplier. Would this not work just as well ?

Comment: If you just applied the CGVector-based impulse to the invisible sprite as-is, you would end up with the arm making quite a few revolutions. :) I have just edited my original post to show you a simple example of how a physics-based arm might point at a given location using velocity, no angle calculation or helper nodes required, you can improve on it as needed.